# Making a "Mad Lib" using the string.replace method and replacing multiple terms

Tags: python, string, replace

This is a question on an assignment, the important part reading: "Prompt the user for strings to replace the various parts of speech that you have specified.  Print out the revised story.  [Hint:  the string method replace(old,new)may be helpful]"

Here is the code I have so far:

```
story = "A long time ago, in a(n) PLACE-ONE far away, lived a BOY-OR-GIRL named NAME. " \
    "They lived with their mother, father, and pet ANIMAL named PET NAME. " \
    "One day, while NAME and PET NAME were playing in the PLACE-TWO, PET NAME " \
    "ran away, and NAME heard a loud SOUND and discovered that PET NAME collided " \
    "with a NOUN, and PET NAME was covered in MESSY-NOUN. As NAME went to go help PET NAME, " \
    "They too became covered in MESSY-NOUN. So they both had to ACTIVE-VERB back to PLACE-ONE and bathe in LIQUID " \
    "to get all clean. The End."
print(story)

place1 = str(input("Enter a place: "))
boyGirl = str(input("Enter a gender (can be a boy or girl): "))
bgName = str(input("Enter a name for your boy or girl: "))
animal = str(input("Enter an animal: "))
animalName = str(input("Enter a name for the animal: "))
place2 = str(input("Enter another place: "))
sound = str(input("Enter a sound: "))
noun1 = str(input("Enter a noun, preferably a large one: "))
messyNoun = str(input("Enter a noun that is messy/dirty: "))
activeVerb = str(input("Enter an action verb: "))
liquid = str(input("Enter a liquid: "))

print(story.replace("PLACE-ONE", place1))
print(story.replace("BOY-OR-GIRL", boyGirl))
print(story.replace("NAME", bgName))
print(story.replace("ANIMAL", animal))
print(story.replace("PET NAME", animalName))
print(story.replace("PLACE-TWO", place2))
print(story.replace("SOUND", sound))
print(story.replace("NOUN", noun1))
print(story.replace("MESSY-NOUN", messyNoun))
print(story.replace("ACTIVE-VERB", activeVerb))
print(story.replace("LIQUID", liquid))
```

Do I need to make a loop to replace everything in the strings?
When I run it, it replaces just that term instead of it, so I just have a bunch of copies of the story with each one only having one term replaced. Or do I need to create a function to do the replacements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`story.replace()` returns a new string, it doesn't change the original string. So every time you call it, you're starting from the original, losing the replacements from the previous line. You need to reassign the result back to `story`:

```
story = story.replace("PLACE-ONE", place1)
story = story.replace("BOY-OR-GIRL", boyGirl)
story = story.replace("NAME", bgName)
story = story.replace("ANIMAL", animal)
story = story.replace("PET NAME", animalName)
story = story.replace("PLACE-TWO", place2)
story = story.replace("SOUND", sound)
story = story.replace("NOUN", noun1)
story = story.replace("MESSY-NOUN", messyNoun)
story = story.replace("ACTIVE-VERB", activeVerb)
story = story.replace("LIQUID", liquid)
print(story)
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't really need a loop, @Barmar answer is totally sufficient but if you don't like typing (like me) or want to make things shorter this may also help:

```
keywords = ["PLACE-ONE","BOY-OR-GIRL","NAME","ANIMAL","PET NAME","PLACE-TWO","SOUND","NOUN","MESSY-NOUN","ACTIVE-VERB","LIQUID"]
replacements = [place1,boyGirl,bgName,animal,animalName,place2,sound,noun1,messyNoun,activeVerb,liquid]


for key,repl in zip(keywords,replacements):
    story = story.replace(key, repl)
```

Hope this was somehow helpful.